# Paypal IPN failing with a Magento site and another different side - collisions

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-ipn

Have a workign Magento 1.7 live site, its Paypal has been fine until recently when another site got attached to the PayPal account it uses.

This other site does not use IPN (Magento site uses PayPal Website Standard payments). However, I think  it is that the other site triggers a IPN notification that goes to the default URL , which is of course set to the livesite's /paypal/ipn/ URL IPN listener.

I have found this thread on a different site http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/errors.php/viewthread/285840/ where some solutoins are given but it seems very inconclusive. What is the recommended way to fix this issue?

1) write dummy script IPN to catch nonIPN Calls and respond with something
2) turn off IPN in paypal account, since Magento may send its own ones anyway (?) 
3) Other solution?

thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set actual IPn url in your paypal account.

IPN url should be posted to paypal( Generally is posted in Magento ) so will result in IPNs to these payment received on stated IPN url.

If you set Magento IPN URL in paypal IPN value then when payment is received by another cart added and if that cart is not posting IPN url when payment related request is posted then IPN will be delivered to URL defined in IPN value on Paypal.

Comment: thanks, if I do not set a IPN URl in PayPal, I have to simply have IPN disabled, as you cannot do this without a URL.

Comment: also - if PayPal IPN is disabled, the Magento status for me stays at Pending Payment, and does not change to Processing. However, it does correctly take payment in PayPal.

Comment: 1)Modify Magento IPN script to check for what was posted in IPN.If this is from other site just acknowledge doing nothing else let the code flow the way Magento IPN code does.

Comment: Thanks Satish yes it seems only way is to write a script on MAgento server that handles the extra notifications. Paypal support have not confirmed this to me though and it would be nice if they made it work more easily than this!

Comment: marked as accepted as you got the closest with what you said - I needed to specify dummy URL in PayPal and have it enabled. (letting MAgento send its own specific URL)

Comment: Good to know you solved it using dummy url and some script.Would be niceif you posted your script so that it is helpful to other people facing same problem.

Comment: it is just a paypal php ipn listener script that was on github. I wish people would actually press PayPal to release the one they used to make public for this as they are more reliable! I am not certain mine will work for every eventuality of their API! Hence bit reluctant to put forward as a ironclad solution, good sir/lady.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct in that if you have IPN configured in your PayPal account it will catch transactions from anything that hits your PayPal account whether it came from Magento or not.

You can indeed disable IPN in the PayPal account and specify an IPN URL with individual payment requests to PayPal.  This is done using NotifyURL in API requests or notify_url in standard buttons.

I'm pretty sure Magento is already doing this by default, but you should probably check.  If it's not you can extend the Magento PayPal module to include this so that you don't have to set it in the PayPal account, which again would get hit for ALL transactions.

Comment: thankyou, I have disabled Paypal IPN and run a test transaction yet the IPNs do not come through to Magento now. This *might* be because the account has had the IPNs disabled however, for too many warnigns/failures. I am trying to check this with PayPal. Very frustrating!

Comment: Further to this, if PayPal IPN is disabled, the Magento status for me stays at Pending Payment, and does not change to Processing. However, it does correctly take payment in PayPal.

Comment: That sounds like Magento must not be using NotifyURL (which is odd).  Have you been able to confirm this yet?

Comment: hi andrew - no it is using the NotifyURL I am pretty certain. I have decided to make an IPN listener on a new default URL I set in PayPal and have that deal with the rogue IPN messages. Magento sets its own url so should be able to happily continue.